# Linear independence and span with trig functions

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Consider the set $V$ of all continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $\{x\sin^2x, x\cos^2x, x\}$. Do these vectors span $\mathbb{R}^3$ and are they linearly independent?

My instinct is no to both. For linear independence I can see a way to solve it by solving simultaneous equations and choosing specific value of $x$. For span i have no idea. Any help would be great!

Comment: Hint: $\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=?$ Can you take one of the three functions away without changing the span?

Comment: @Skorpion so I think this doesnt span R, since for example we cannot form $f(x)=x^2$ from a linear combination of these vectors. Is this correct?

Comment: Right, you can't get $x^2$. Just wanna point out one thing -- here we are treating _functions_ as abstract _vectors_ or _points_ in a _function space_. You'll see it more often soon. :)

Comment: @Skorpion thanks! I believe I have just proved they are linearly independent though ; is this also correct? As i said initially this contradicted my gut feeling...

Comment: What do you get from $x \sin^2x+x\cos^2x = x(\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x)$? Some things cancel don't they :)

Comment: @Skorpion so we'll get $x$ from that, and adding to the third component gives 2x. I don't see how to determine independence from that though

Comment: $x\sin^2 x+x\cos^2x-x=x-x=0$ so you get a nontrivial (i.e., coefficient nonzero) combination resulting in $0$. Subtraction works just fine since coefficients can be negative. That, by definition, shows that the three functions are not L.I.